# Should I use a Map storing the id, or iterate over entries to find an object?

Tags: java, object, collections

I'm wondering which of the following approaches I should use when finding an entry with an id from a collection?

**Using a map**

```
Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<>();

public MyObject getById(String id) {
  return map.get(id);
}
```

**Using a list/set**

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

public MyObject getObjectById(String id) {
    for (MyObject object : list) {
        if (object.getId().equals(id)) {
            return object;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Without having a specific use case, which would be recommended to use?

Comment: Well, in this case, either.

Comment: A “specific use case” is exactly what this Question needed. Without criteria as to goals and judging success, how can we provide an Answer?

Comment: @BasilBourque Maybe just like how @ CalebKeller was perfectly able to provide an answer to the scenario when used under general circumstances? Or maybe you disagree with his answer..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use a HashMap, you absolutely should. Retrieving an item from a HashMap using its key takes a constant amount of time, but iterating through an array takes time proportional to the number of elements in the array. In more technical terms, the lookup using a HashMap is O(1), while the lookup using an ArrayList is O(n).

What that means is the code that uses a HashMap will always be fast, but the code that uses the ArrayList will slow down significantly as you add more elements to it.

Comment: Ah okay very nice, thank you!

With that said, would you recommend to use an ArrayList *if you know* the collection will always remain small? Can that out-beat the Map?

Comment: @Liam I believe so. There is some overhead to a map, so if the list was only a few items it could be faster. But in that case, they would both be so fast, it would hardly matter. Still, the thing to do if that really matters is profile. Look up the Java Microbenchmark Harness (JMH).

Comment: Consider that a map is not a direct one to one lookup.  The get method will get the proper "bucket" for the key.  Then the bucket will need to be searched for the key to retrieve the associated value. But it is still more efficient for large numbers of items than a list.

Comment: Alrighty thank you both :), I'll have a look into the microbenchmark as well